# How can blind worm aliens travel into space if they cannot even see stars?

Tags: technology, aliens, space-travel

In several previous questions I asked about aliens native to an eyeball earth that evolved from burrowers. They have a serpentine shape and hold their heads up like cobras. I've concluded they wouldn't have eyes at all and just use sonar and heat pits. As well as touch of course. How could such a species travel into space if they couldn't even see stars. The only ideas I have involve enslavement by another spacefaring species or a crash landing.

Comment: not only would sonar not work in space, it will likely also be extremally confusing since and sound they make would just echo through their body until being absorbed.

Comment: You're putting the cart before the horse by worrying about space travel before basic tech development. FYI, humans discovered X-rays and radio waves and radio telescopes before we could travel into space. How is this any different? Heck, we discovered the CMB by messing around with radios on Earth without even meaning to look at the sky.

Comment: @John You could argue the same with vision to be honest, yet humans can navigate in the presence of reflections, glare, uneven lighting, etc. Although we do have trouble in a house of mirrors.

Comment: @DKNguyen now imagine navigating in a room where light is impossible. this is like a pitch black room with lights glue facing inwards towards your eyes that turn on every time you exhale. sound simply does not exist in space sonar cannot work.

Comment: @John I was referring to your statement about general navigation using sound: "extremely confusing since and sound they make would just echo through their body until being absorbed". That statement is taking for granted the way human brains are wired for vision and ignoring the difficulties that must be dealt with. But if you want to talk specifically about navigating in space, who said we were limited to sonar?

Comment: @DKNguyen the OP said that, sonar is their main sense. And I am sorry that was confusing I was specifically thinking of them in space suits. Space completely changes how that sense works, because the energy from the sonar pulse can't go anywhere outside the suit. psycologically the effect would be similar to if gong into space made light randomly change intensity and wavelength, it would be completely disorienting.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming heat pits in your species work the same as Earth Snakes, your species *can* see light — [infrared light](https://herpetoculturenetwork.com/heat-pits-explained/).

Humans routinely convert light signals from one wavelength to another. Consider recent images from the James Webb Space Telescope. We see those images in the visible light spectrum, but they were originally captured in the infrared spectrum. Computer algorithms converted that light into colors we can perceive. There is nothing stopping your species from developing the same technology.